# My <input type="image"> is not working like a <button type="submit">

Tags: html

I used to have a submit button like this:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I've now replaced the text with a swanky image that fits the look and feel of my site, but strangely, this isn't working:

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.gif" alt="Submit" />
```

In particular, the form "submits", but the other form input values aren't submitted properly.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very special situation, it turned out.

My form happened to have these two values:
    `<input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />`
    `<input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />`

When you change to input type="image", and click submit, variables named x and y return the point at which the user clicked on the submit button - overwriting my actual useful variables x and y.

Renamed my form variables to x-coord and y-coord and it worked perfectly.